# Phonegap camera take a picture

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I'm working on adding some mobile app specific functionality to my mobile website. Currently, the app is more or less just a wrapper.

```
public class Activity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (this.isOnline()) {
            super.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");
        } else {
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/offline.html");
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem rises with the following javascript. If I replace super.loadUrl("http://mysite.com"); with super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/online.html") and run the following javascript there, it works fine. But if I run it on mysite.com, it keeps on throwing the following exception:

07-13 12:25:12.762: E/Web Console(28251): Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/data/com.my.app/.Pic.jpg?1342171460960 at null:0

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
 var camera = (function(){

        var camera = {
            settings : {
                quality: 50, 
            }
        };

        var error = function(message) {
            console.error("Error happened while trying to get a picture", message);
        };

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

            camera.settings.destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI;    

            camera.fromPhone = function() {
                this.settings.sourceType = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
                return this;
            };

            camera.fromLibrary = function() {
                this.settings.sourceType = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
                return this;
            };

            camera.get  = function(callback) {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(callback, error, camera.settings);
            };

        }, false);


        return camera;

 })();

//Later, at a click event
camera.fromPhone().get(function(imageURI){
    alert("imageURI" + imageURI)
    $("#largeImage").attr("src", imageURI);
});
```

Comment: Are you using Phonegap for a website or as a mobile application? If the latter, what platform are you developing for?
This is important because sometimes you have to explicitly allow external data to be loaded in applications. In iOS, one would specify this in Appname-Info.plist under URL types.

Also, I don't think the title of your question matches the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your remotely loaded site can not access the local resources due to browser cross domain security. This is an old thread but explains some reasons for it.

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2009-May/007658.html